# how to display right-to-left languages (Arabic, Persian, Urdu) in conky?

Tags: language, conky, arabic

I don't mean alignment of the text within conky. If I enter the text in conky, the letters are displayed in the wrong order. If you look at the text and you look at the output, the order is all wrong. English is a Left to Right language (i.e. A B C --->), the language i'm trying to enter is Right to Left (<--- خ و ش) but it is displayed like english (LTR) instead of its proper order (RTL):

خ و ش is displayed as ش و خ

In addition, most RTL languages use words that join together (e.g. خ و ش is actually written as خوش )

If anybody knows how to display these languages properly in conky, PLEASE answer this.

Answer (score 0):

Use Google translate then copy and paste. You can also use Word and/or Open Office with the appropriate language pack then copy and paste and provided you have the language set to the desired language i.e Arabic everything aligns corectly and joins perfectly.
For example:

```
بعد التحية والسلام
دخول 
خروج 
داخل 
خارج 
الذهاب إلى الداخل
```

Google Translate uses formal Arabic, Urdu, etc. If you want to use a word like Chosh  خوش جوا which is informal for go inside, you will need to add this to Google translate.
Hope this helps

Comment: Doesnot work in **conky**